# JAVA create and edit file in project

Tags: java, spring, file

I have a project (maven project if that's important) with the class at this location:
`src/main/java` package: `com.myapp.things`.
Is it possible programmatically, in this class, to create/edit files in the same project, but with location: `src/test/casper/utils`?

If yes, some code samples will be nice.

Comment: not enough information to answer, edit your question and explain in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new files and folders in your project, but if you plan on making it into an executable jar, you may run into problems if your program tries to access a file inside of your jar because it will not be able to find the path.

To access the path of you project you can do

```
String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

This will give you the path of your project and you can use that location to specify where to make and edit files in your project folder.